# Joining table which are not related with one another laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, join, orm

just want to ask some question related to joining table

I want to know if it is possible to join 2 tables together even though they are not in a relationship with one another. Is this possible? If yes, could you give me an example on how it is done. If no, is there any other way to join or relate the 2 tables even though it doesn't have any foreign key (eg:user_id)

I saw for sql they use something like cross join but can you do it in laravel as well?

Sample table for example: (let say I want to make the verification table name_of_user equal to user information table's name)

So something like verification.name_of_user = user_information.name

verify user information table:

```
Schema::create(verifications, function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('name_of_user'); 
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

user information table:

```
Schema::create(user_info, function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('name); 
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are these tables indirectly related? ie when you make a diagram of your db, are the tables connected through one or more other tables? if yes, then you can join them together using multiple join statements.

If not, there are some cases where you could join them on same values, even if they are not foreign keys.

**Edit:** yes you can join these 2 tables on the name attribute, but you would have to use an sql query and not eloquent.

```
SELECT v.*, u.* 
FROM verifications AS v
JOIN user_info AS u 
    ON u.name = v.name_of_user
```

**Warning**:
Even if it is possible, I would not recommend it, since there could be multiple entries with the same name / name_of_user.
Instead, create a user table and replace verifications.name_of_user with verifications.user_id and user_info.name with user_info.user_id.
Then you can join on the user_id and ALWAYS get correctly joined results.

```
Schema::create(users, function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('name');
});

Schema::create(verifications, function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->integer('user_id'); 
    $table->timestamps();
});

Schema::create(user_info, function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->integer('user_id'); 
    $table->timestamps();
});

SELECT v.*, u.* 
FROM verifications AS v
JOIN user_info AS u 
    ON u.user_id = v.user_id
```

I havent used laravel/eloquent in a while now, but I think if you set it up right you can now even use normal eloquent methods to join these, since the user_id is now (if set up correctly) a foreign key and therefore the tables are related ;)

Comment: they are not related by anything at all, no relationship, no foreign key and etc, and I want to know if it is possible to do a join statement for those 2 tables. Could you show me an example if possible from your answer

Comment: I understand now that you ask for a specific table design and not just as a theoretical question. In this case, can you maybe show the structure of these 2 tables?

Comment: Sure hold on while I update my question and put in a sample table

Comment: Sorry I think I might need some time to think of an example, can't really think of 1 hahaha

Comment: so.. it IS a theroetical question?

Comment: Done, I think it something like this, just want to know if it is possible to do it

Comment: So is it possible to do a join statement between this 2 tables? Like just a normal join statement with no where statement and stuff

Comment: I can't believe the answer is always in front of me , the part "u.name = v.name_of_user" is the important part right?

Comment: yes :)  to join two tables you need a column on both tables that has the same value. these will be the columns that you join the tables with. In your case, its the name / name_of_user. It *could* be possible to join on the timestamps if its what you wanted, but i couldn't possibly see any use-case for that.

Comment: Must it be the same? Does it have something like contain or LIKE statement? For example what if my name I put john but name_of_user I put John Doe, then won't the value be different?

Comment: It isnt't the same value, so it would not join these two together. Usually you join tables on foreign keys so you know for sure that it joins the right entries together. A downside of joining String columns is that there could be two entries 'John' and therefore the result will have incorrectly joined entries.

Comment: Ohhh, I see thanks for explaining to me in clear terms :)

Comment: Thank you for the additional information, will consider doing that and also thank you so much for your help  :)

Answer (score 0):

Check following query,

```
SELECT t1.Country,t2.* FROM table_1 as t1, table_2 as t2 where t1.id='1' and t2.id='2'
```

Comment: then what if I want to get name from table_1 and table_2 I want to get Country?

Comment: For this part, where t1.id='1' and t2.id='2', why is there a need for their id? I thought if they are not related why is the id still involved here